# JavaScript code injection without a <script> tag

Tags: javascript, popup, wmd, shadowbox

A client script is pulling some HTML from a server into an in-page popup (shadowbox and the like).

I suspect this is being done via jQuery's `.html()` somewhere.

Long story short, the following fails:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> myFunc(); </script>
```

Unfortunately, I can't modify the client side code (so I can't pass and execute the JavaScript code via an alternative channel).

One way I got this working is by returning the following as part of the HTML:

```
<img src="." onerror=" myFunc(); "/>
```

In hindsight, I could have used a valid image URL an `onload`, but if both events work, I'd rather used a bad path to make the browser cause invocation immediately (and one less HTTP/cache lookup).

With regards to the setup so far, I'll like to hear your opinion about it, and perhaps a better solution.

**Edit:**

Let's assume this is the client code which I can't mess with:

```
jQuery.get('test.php',function(data){
    jQuery('#popup').html(data);
});
```

This is the data returned by `test.php`:

```
Hello!
<script type=text/javascript> myFunc(); </script>
```

And the following is my proposed solution:

```
Hello!
<img src="." onerror=" myFunc(); "/>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure if the page is pulling in your HTML via AJAX, then you'd have to trigger your JS via some sort of event. The only drawback to yours is that it's an extra server-ping.

Comment: Do you realize that you're basically asking how to do potential XSS attack?

Comment: @BalusC - Why would it be an XSS if it's running on the same domain? I simply need to execute the JS parts from a block of HTML.

Comment: @DA - I'm still pulling the HTML; that `img` tag is inside the returned HTML!

Comment: An image SRC attribute is going to ping the server to ask for the image

Comment: @DA not if the SRC is so malformed the browser doesn't know what it means. In this case I checked it via firebug, no additional requests sent.

Comment: @Christian...you may be right, though I'd do a cursory check on some other browsers as well.

Comment: @BalusC, I'm not sure I follow your reasoning, but what I meant is that the server is generating some code which unconditionally shows a popup that tries to load my actual page content. There's no hint of XSS in all of this.

Comment: @DA - Right. I've been a bit afraid this might not work on non-IE browsers. Apparently `onerror` is not W3C-approved.

Comment: Sorry, then I apparently don't understand your ignorance about the client side environment details. Ignore the above comments then.

Comment: @BalusC - See my edited question, should be more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onload on the `<body>`.

```
<body onload="myFunc();">
```

Comment: That won't work obviously. I'm not returning a full HTML page, just an excerpt. I'll edit my question with a clarification

Comment: Do you have access to the file test.php? In that case I would return a JSON with it, an array with two fields. JS and HTML. Then you could use JavaScript's `eval()` and inject the HTML.

Comment: No, I already explained this above in the part about "alternative channels". By the way, `test.php` is hypothetical - it is in fact the output of a CMS, so it's difficult and problematic to hack the CMS core for this fix.